# Pocos - The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, poco

I have three tables, and they are user, user_details and user_acls. The user table is master table, and the other two are children tables that store information related to the user. The foreign key in the latter two tables is user_id, and user_id is the primary key on the user table.

Using entity framework and pocos I have set up the following class structure, and I will only do it for one of my child tables, as once I have this resolved I should be able to apply the same logic to my other user table.

User Class

```
namespace myclass.Core.Domain.Customers
{

    public partial class User : BaseEntity
    {
        private ICollection<UsersSitesAcl> _usersSitesAcls;
        private ICollection<CompaniesAcl> _companiesAcls;
        private ICollection<UserDetails> _userDetails;

        public virtual Guid userguid { get; set; }
        public virtual string first_name { get; set; }
        public virtual string last_name { get; set; }
        public virtual string email_address { get; set; }
        public virtual System.DateTime? activated_date { get; set; }
        public virtual string pwrd { get; set; }
        public virtual string loginname { get; set; }
        public virtual string title { get; set; }
        public virtual string suffix { get; set; }
        public virtual string secretquestion { get; set; }
        public virtual string secretanswer { get; set; }
        public virtual long? birthyear { get; set; }
        public virtual string last_four_ssn { get; set; }
        public virtual bool? suspended_yn { get; set; }
        public virtual string account_status { get; set; }



        public virtual ICollection<UsersSitesAcl> usersSitesAcls
        {
            get
            {
                var sitesAcls = new List<UsersSitesAcl>();
                if (_usersSitesAcls != null)
                {
                    var query = from usa in _usersSitesAcls
                                where usa.active_yn
                                select usa;

                    sitesAcls = query.ToList();
                }
                return sitesAcls;
            }
            protected set { _usersSitesAcls = value; }
        }

        public virtual ICollection<CompaniesAcl> companiesAcls
        {
            get
            {
                var companyAcls = new List<CompaniesAcl>();
                if (_companiesAcls != null)
                {
                    var query = from ca in _companiesAcls
                                where ca.active_yn
                                select ca;

                    companyAcls = query.ToList();
                }
                return companyAcls;
            }
            protected set { _companiesAcls = value; }
        }


        public virtual ICollection<UserDetails> userDetails
        {
            get
            {
                var userDetails = new List<UserDetails>();
                if (_userDetails != null)
                {
                    userDetails = (from ud in _userDetails where ud.active_yn select ud).ToList();
                }
                return userDetails;
            }
             set { _userDetails = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

User Details Class

```
namespace myclass.Core.Domain.Customers
{
    public partial class UserDetails : BaseEntity
    {
        private User _updatedByUser;

        public virtual long user_id { get; set; }
        public virtual string primary_specialty { get; set; }
        public virtual string secondary_specialty { get; set; }
        public virtual string npi { get; set; }
        public virtual string state_licence_number { get; set; }
        public virtual string issuing_state { get; set; }
        public virtual string dea_number { get; set; }
        public virtual string dea_schedule1 { get; set; }
        public virtual string dea_schedule2 { get; set; }
        public virtual string dea_schedule3 { get; set; }
        public virtual string dea_schedule4 { get; set; }
        public virtual string dea_schedule5 { get; set; }
        public virtual string dea_expire_date { get; set; }
        public virtual string state_licence_expire_date { get; set; }
        public virtual string provider_rights { get; set; }
        public virtual long updated_by_user_id { get; set; }
        public virtual User updatedByUser
        {
            get { return _updatedByUser; }
            protected set
            {
                _updatedByUser = value;
                updated_by_user_id = _updatedByUser.Id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For my mapping I have the following structure for both the user and user details
UserMap

```
namespace myclass.Data.Mappings.Domains.Customers
{
    public partial class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("users");
            this.HasKey(u => u.Id);
            this.Property(u => u.Id).HasColumnName("user_id");
            this.Property(u => u.userguid).IsRequired();
            this.Property(u => u.first_name).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
            this.Property(u => u.last_name).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
            this.Property(u => u.pwrd).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
            this.Property(u => u.email_address).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
            this.Property(u => u.loginname).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
            this.Property(u => u.activated_date).IsOptional();
            this.Property(u => u.create_date).IsRequired();
            this.Property(u => u.active_yn).IsRequired();
            this.Property(u => u.title).IsOptional();
            this.Property(u => u.suffix).IsOptional();
            this.Property(u => u.last_four_ssn).IsOptional();
            this.Property(u => u.secretquestion).IsOptional();
            this.Property(u => u.secretanswer).IsOptional();
            this.Property(u => u.birthyear).IsOptional();
            this.Property(u => u.account_status).IsOptional();
            this.Property(u => u.suspended_yn).IsOptional();

            this.HasMany(u => u.userDetails).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ud => ud.user_id);
            this.HasMany(u => u.usersSitesAcls).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(usa => usa.user_id);
            this.HasMany(u => u.companiesAcls).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ca => ca.user_id);
        }
    }
}
```

UserDetails Map

```
enter code here
namespace myclass.Data.Mappings.Domains.Customers
{
    public partial class UserDetailsMap:EntityTypeConfiguration<UserDetails>
    {
        public UserDetailsMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("user_details");
            this.HasKey(ud => ud.Id);
            this.Property(ud => ud.Id).HasColumnName("user_detail_id");
            this.Property(ud => ud.user_id).IsRequired();
            this.Property(ud => ud.primary_specialty).HasColumnName("primary_speciality").IsOptional();
            this.Property(ud => ud.secondary_specialty).IsOptional();
            this.Property(ud => ud.npi).IsOptional();
            this.Property(ud => ud.state_licence_number).HasColumnName("StateLicenseNumber").IsOptional();
            this.Property(ud => ud.issuing_state).HasColumnName("IssuingState").IsOptional();
            this.Property(ud => ud.dea_number).HasColumnName("DEANumber").IsOptional();
            this.Property(ud => ud.dea_schedule1).HasColumnName("DEASchedule1").IsOptional();
            this.Property(ud => ud.dea_schedule2).HasColumnName("DEASchedule2").IsOptional();
            this.Property(ud => ud.dea_schedule3).HasColumnName("DEASchedule3").IsOptional();
            this.Property(ud => ud.dea_schedule4).HasColumnName("DEASchedule4").IsOptional();
            this.Property(ud => ud.dea_schedule5).HasColumnName("DEASchedule5").IsOptional();
            this.Property(ud => ud.dea_expire_date).HasColumnName("DeaExpireDate").IsOptional();
            this.Property(ud => ud.state_licence_expire_date).HasColumnName("StateLicenseExpireDate").IsOptional();
            this.Property(ud => ud.provider_rights).HasColumnName("ProviderRights").IsOptional();
            this.Property(ud => ud.active_yn).IsRequired();
            this.Property(ud => ud.create_date).IsRequired();
            this.Property(ud => ud.updated_by_user_id).IsRequired();

            this.HasRequired(ud => ud.updatedByUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(ud => ud.updated_by_user_id);
        //
}
    }
}
```

First of I am adding a new record, and I set the contents of the User class (bar the User_details and user_acls, and it goes out and creates the record for the user without any issues.

However, when I try to do the same for the user_details and user_acls, I have not had any success, and have tried to adding the user_details as item to the property on the user table without any success.

And have even tried saving it out as a separate record, where I store the user record, retrieve the user_id of the new record added. Then create a new object for user_details and user_acls, and try to a save on that and I end up with the following message:

What do I need to do to make this work, I have tried everything I know and no success. So any help ye can give would be appreciated. Thanks.

> Blockquote
>   The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code to read but I think the issue is that you're modifying the entity state while it's not being tracked by the entity framework.

Try something like

```
     db.Entry(currentyUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

before saving changes.

Comment: I should have added in here, that this is using the repository pattern to write the record out, so after I set the object i pass it into the respository insert method. Which has the following code.

Comment: if(entity == null)
                   throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

               this.Entities.Add(entity);
               
               this._context.SaveChanges();
               _inserted_record_id = entity.Id;

Comment: The other thing I should note here, is that this only occurs when I am storing a new user. I add the user, and then I add in the user_details, which dont exist and there is no record associated with that user being added to the db. It creates the user record, just none of the children records.

Answer (score 0):

You show a lot of code but not, I suspect, the code in question.i.e. how you create a user and attach user detail and then how you save those objects.

A simple test can be to use

```
this.Ignore(ud=>ud.User)
```

as part of your user detail mapping.

If this works you can be fairly certain the issue is that the User associated with the UserDetail has a state other than Unchanged. What should be happening is that the User should be getting saved first and then having its state set to Unchanged and then the User Details should be getting saved.

Because you dont show your attach and save code I can only speculate but I would bet money that the state of User is not Unchanged, probably Added or some custom state like Inactive if you are using disconnected entities.

Therefore EF tries to recreate the User object ( if state == Added) and then reassign it to the UserDetails which somehow orphans the User Details by nulling the previous User object association and then attaching the new.

I'm still working through the docs on exactly how this happens but my own experience just this last half hour has been that the parent / foreign key object had a state other than Unchanged. So EF is differentiating the reference of User in your User Details object from what it has in it's DBSets. Thus the null reference.

I understand you are saving a new  User and their details at the same time but look carefully at your code as to how you do that. Most likely there is some kind of "User swap" going on whereby the User you save first is not actually the User that's attached to UserDetails when trying to save them. Are you doing any Linq ToList() type "stuff" and inadvertently switching references to an non Unchanged User object.

In my case it was because I was creating a "stub" object in code of an FK object in the db and I overlooked    settings it's state to Unchanged before associating it with my detail object.

Sorry that my answer is a bit of a waffle but Im just working it through it now. When I understand it more consisely I will update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and it had to do with the way I was accessing the user object using autofac, in the end it was something on my end.